# Is it possible to add date picker in microsoft bot framework application while taking date inputs?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Suppose if the bot wants date of birth of user. Can it present it
with the datepicker instead of asking user to type it in dd/mm/yyyy etc format ?

[image]

Please care to comment if any problem in the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no datepicker available "as is". It may depend on the channel you will be using, your question is unclear about that point.

One interesting feature may be to use AdaptiveCards as **in some channels** it allows datepickers, like for Webchat (see the sample [here](http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=WebChat%20(Bot%20Framework)))

[image: sample for webchat]

But this is not working for Slack, Facebook Messenger, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This would solve my problem.

Comment: How we can write same code in .NET SDK ( C#) . If anyone knows, please. provide same. Do we have this solution in github. Share link .